# Script STOPS when Source URL is not Status 200

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, web-scraping

I have a script (see below) that checks (more or less) linkpositions on a website, it works fine but as soon as the source url on which the link lies is not a 200 response it will quit, I just want it to jump ahead to the next or give back some message "error" or even better give me back the http status code. I need a quick solution, if anyone can help me that would be super awesome :)

`URLs.csv` = list of websites that contain a link to a certain page
`domain.com` = domain for which to check whether a link is there or not and if yes where is it located roughly.

```
import csv
from lxml import html

with open('URLs.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    urls = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

for url in urls:
    print url

    doc = html.parse(url)
    if doc.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"domain.com")]'):
        for anchor_node in doc.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"finanzen.de")]'):
            if anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "sidebar")]'):
                print 'Sidebar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./parent::div[contains(@class, "widget")]'):
                print 'Sidebar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "sidebar")]'):
                print 'Sidebar'            
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "comment")]'):
                print 'Kommentar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "comment")]'):
                print 'Kommentar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "foot")]'):
                print "Footer"
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "foot")]'):
                print "Footer"
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "post")]'):
                print "Contextual"
            else:
                print 'Unidentified Link'
        else:
            print 'Link is Dead'
```

Python-Shell

```
            Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
            Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
            [evaluate Linkidentifizierung.py]
            http://urlnotworking.com/broken.html
            Rückverfolgung (innerste zuletzt):
            File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py",     line 11, in <module>
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 735, in parse
        return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 3197, in  lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:64726)
       H‹GH‹ÏÿP0H…ÛtHƒÿu
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 1571, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:92363)
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 1600, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:92647)
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 1500, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91710)
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 1047, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:88610)
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 577, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:84019)
            File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 676, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:85122)
           File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd", line 614, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:84417)
    IOError: Error reading file 'http://urlnotworking.com/broken.html':  failed to load HTTP resource
```

Comment: I had to fix your indentation; can you please verify everything is correct now?

Comment: Thanks, im still very new here :) but my problem remains, it works just as long as every URL seems to have a 200 response, if not it will generate the python-shell as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

```
print url

try:
  html.parse(url)
except Exception, e:
  print "something went wrong: %s" % e
  continue

if doc.xpath....
```

I'm not familiar enough with the lxml.html library to see if you can get anything more detailed about why the URL failed to load.  (Hint -- I would use the "requests" library to load my urls, then pass the results off to the lxml parser.)